# replicaof directive not allowed in cluster mode

Tags: kubernetes, redis, kubernetes-helm

I am installing redis cluster using helm v3.2.1 via this command :

```
./helm install stable/redis-ha --generate-name -n middleware
```

But, when I start the redis cluster, It gives me error :

```
*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 12
>>> 'slaveof 10.111.179.78 6379'
replicaof directive not allowed in cluster mode
```

Can you help me find the issue and what should I do to make it work?

Some people said to turn `cluster-enabled` to no but I do not think it is a wise decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should comment `slaveof 10.111.179.78 6379`.

With Redis Cluster, in order to make a node be a replica of another, you should call the [CLUSTER REPLICATE](https://redis.io/commands/cluster-replicate) command, NOT specifying the `slaveof` config.

I'm not familiar with Kubernetes-helm, and not sure if it will automatically call this command. You can remove the `slaveof` config, and try again.